# Testing the process of assigning offers to a customer

Tags: c#, unit-testing, bdd

I asked a similar question yesterday, which was criticised because I posted the test without the supporting code.  Therefore I deleted the question yesterday as it was not clear enough.  I am now going to post it again with the supporting code. Please see the test code below:

```
[TestFixture]
public class CustomerTest
{
    private IList<Product> _products;
    private Concor _concor;
    private Chestnut _chestnut;

    private IOfferCalculator _offerCalculator;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void OneTimeSetUp()
    {
        _offerCalculator = new OfferCalculator();
    }

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _concor = new Concor();
        _chestnut = new Chestnut();
        _products = new List<Product>();
        _products.Add(_concor);
        _products.Add(_chestnut);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Should_receive_a_for_concor()
    {
        var expectedConcor = new List<Product>();
        expectedConcor.Add(_concor);
        var gender = "F";
        var expenditure = 1500M;
        var Customer = new Customer(gender,expenditure);
        //Act
        Customer.AssignOffers(_offerCalculator, _products);
        //Assert
        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(Customer._assignedProducts, expectedConcor);
    }
}
```

Here is the supporting code:

```
public class Concor : Product
    {
        public override bool Check(Customer customer)
        {
            if (customer._expenditure > 100 && customer._gender == "F")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    public class Chestnut : Product
    {
        public override bool Check(Customer customer)
        {
            if (customer._expenditure >  100 && customer._gender =="M")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    public abstract class Product
    {
        public abstract bool Check(Customer customer);
    }

    public interface IOfferCalculator
    {
        IEnumerable<Product> Calculate(Customer customer, IList<Product> products);
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public string _gender { get; protected set; }
        public decimal _expenditure { get; protected set; }
        public IList<Product> _assignedProducts = new List<Product>();

        public Customer(string gender, decimal expenditure)
        {
            _gender = gender;
            _expenditure = expenditure;
        }

        public void AssignOffers(IOfferCalculator offerCalculator, IList<Product> products)
        {
            foreach (var product in offerCalculator.Calculate(this, products))
            {
                if (!_assignedProducts.Contains(product))
                {
                    _assignedProducts.Add(product);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class OfferCalculator : IOfferCalculator
    {
        public IEnumerable<Product> Calculate(Customer customer, IList<Product> products)
        {
            foreach (var product in products)
            {
                if (product.Check(customer))
                {
                    yield return product;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I would like some feedback about the quality of the test.  The company like to use BDD, however I am conscious that I asserting state rather than behaviour (arguing that I am testing calculations rather than orchestrations).  I would also like some feedback about my use of the: OneTimeSetup attribute and Setup attribute.  Also How would I test for a Chestnut? Add a new method or use an attribute for the test cases?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are asking about your tests but there are issues in your code that should be addressed before you start testing.

---

> ```
> public abstract class Product
> {
>     public abstract bool Check(Customer customer);
> }
> ```

You made `Product` an abstract class but this is not necessary. It does not provide any default implementation for anything so an simple interface would be enough.

There is however one more issue with it. The `Check` method. It doesn't say anything about what is being checked.

> ```
> customer._expenditure >  100 && customer._gender =="M"
> ```

Its implementation evaluates the above condition but there is no information about it in the method name so nobody could tell what it checks.

On top of it it even uses the hardcoded magic-number `100`. This should be a constant.

You also put it inside an `if/else` which isn't necessary. You can just `return` the result.

---

> ```
> public void AssignOffers(IOfferCalculator offerCalculator, IList<Product> products)
> {
>     foreach (var product in offerCalculator.Calculate(this, products))
>     {
>         if (!_assignedProducts.Contains(product))
>         {
>             _assignedProducts.Add(product);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

This is the method you test but it's difficult to test it because it's doing to much: it filters the product list, it checks whether it's assigned and it adds it to another list. To me these are three different responsibilities. You should at least pass an already filtered product list.

The method also does not inform me that anything will be filtered at all. It says `AssignOffers` but instead of assing offers it calculates something and it works with producs that it adds to another list but it does not assign anything. Everything is misleading about this method and it's full of surprises.

---

Having said that I find all your tests are meaningless because the implementation is meaningless too. The code is confusing and doing completely different things that the names would suggest. Writing tests for such code is pointless.

You should first fix the main code so that it's clear what it does so that you know what you test. Try to pick names that clearly communicate the purpose and do exacly only that.

For exmaple if you `Calculate` something then let this method return a result of this calculation based on as few parameters as possible. Passing entire objects where you only need two properties is a code smell.

---

> ```
> public IEnumerable<Product> Calculate(Customer customer, IList<Product> products)
> {
>     foreach (var product in products)
>     {
>         if (product.Check(customer))
>         {
>             yield return product;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

But wait a minute! Let's take a look at what `Calculate` actually does... to my (not) surprise it does not calculate anything but instead it checks products against a customer!!! How confusing is that?

---

This is such a mess that you can throw all these tests away and first rewrite the code completely then write new tests.

Comment: Many thanks +1.  I will make the changes you suggest and post another question.

Comment: You say that AssignOffers is doing too much and doesn't assign anything.  It assigns an offer (product) to a list.  What is wrong with that? Also how does it do too much? Thanks.

Comment: @w0051977 1) yes it does do too much: it filters the list with `Calculate`  (!!!), it checks whether the list `Contains` a product and only then it adds a product to a list so it does three different things. 2)  adding with `Add` is not the same as assignment with the `=` sign which would mean `product.Offer = offer` or something similar. But this is not what this method is doing.

Comment: I see.  So if I remove the if statement then it is simple enough? Thanks.  The reason I have the check is because I used a hashset instead of a list.  I guess it is ok to have the if statement if there is a hashset?

Comment: @w0051977 sorry, I cannot answer this question because I don't know what you are going to achieve. Ask yourself what is this (or any other) method supposed to do and do only that. No filtering no anything else. If it needs to filter something then create another method that only filters producs and give the first one a filtered list.

Comment: Thank you.  So in that case, AssignProducts will call something like: FilterProducts to get a filtered list?

Comment: @w0051977 not exactly, it already does that. I should receive a list of products that is alread filtered. If it should assign anything then that's all what it should do. Calling FilterProducs is another responsibility. If you do that the you'd have to call it `FilterAndAssignProducs` but the `And` in the nama indicates the method is doing more then it should.

Comment: The only reservation I have about that is the client app has to call two methods instead of one?

Comment: @w0051977 that's right and that's the purpose of splitting it. The client knows it uses a filtered list and doesn't wonder why the result is different from what anyone would have expected.

Comment: Thanks.  That makes sense.  However, what if the client developer forgets to call Filter and assigns all products! (there are only two products at the moment but there will be a lot more).

Comment: @w0051977 he can do it anyway if he only writes his own `IOfferCalculator` that doesn't do anything so he might as well use it before calling `AssignProducts` - this is all very confusing.

Comment: You say use constants instead of magic strings/numbers.  Should these constants be public or private?

Comment: @w0051977 it depends... if it's a framework then definitely public so that people can see what defaults are used, if it's just some self-contained tool then they might be as well privaste.

Comment: it is a domain model, which will be used by an application services layer so I guess they should be public?

Comment: I have attempted this again here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/186148/testing-the-process-of-assigning-offers-to-a-customer-2.  Please take a look.  Thanks.

Comment: May I ask what you think of an abstract base class for Entity and ValueObject as described here: enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2014/11/08/domain-object-base-cl‌​ass . I am thinking abiout adding them.

Comment: @w0051977 doesn't look very useful to me as a simple Id equality is nearly never what you want. Most of the time it's some first/last name combination, telephone number, pattern or other data.

Comment: thank you.  I thought Entities should be compared by ID? What about a base type for ValueObjects (https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2007/06/25/generic-value-object-equality/)? I may ask a question on here about the Entity class as I am using it in an early but growing app.

Comment: @w0051977 the Id is only for the database so that it can address each record by a unique identifier. However, I can still have two persons with the exact same data but having different Ids - so, not really helpful ;-] Too much unnecessary science. I wouldn't implement any general equality. I do it when a particular entity type requires it and only for properties I need.

Comment: I here what you are saying about IDs being a database concern in the data model.  However, I believe Entities in the domain model are the same? For example, there are 100s of Adam Smiths in my system and they are all different.  I guess you would have to match on firstname; surname and date of birth.  What about a base value type?

Comment: with regards to the following quote from your answer: "Passing entire objects where you only need two properties is a code smell".  Please see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39349812/ddd-instantiate-value-objects-inside-aggregate-or-pass-it-as-parameter.  If Customer contained validation logic for gender and expenditure then I assume you would advocate passing the object rather than parameters (Gender and Expenditure)?